# Empty constructor for kotlin object to use Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm trying to save an object inside Firebase database from Kotlin,
I dont feel right providing a default empty constructor and put values as `nullable`, having to change all my code bc of this.

My class:

```
class Video(var id: String, var url: String, var owner: User) :  {
    constructor() : this("", "", User("", "", ""))
}
```

Firebase push:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("public").push().setValue(video)
```

Error:

> is missing a constructor with no arguments

Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use default arguments:

```
class Video(var id: String = "", var url: String = "",
    var owner: User = User("", "", ""))
```

(also, consider using `val`).

Comment: `val` is immutable. The deserializer won't be able to set the actual values, and you'll end up having a bunch of objects with the same (default) values.

Answer (score 5):

I have not tested if it works with Firebase, but according to the [kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#secondary-constructors),

> NOTE: On the JVM, if all of the parameters of the primary constructor have default values, the compiler will generate an additional parameterless constructor which will use the default values. This makes it easier to use Kotlin with libraries such as Jackson or JPA that create class instances through parameterless constructors.

So I suppose, by applying default values for all the constructor parameters will generate the parameterless constructor for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an empty constructor to the Video class. This is required to be able to use classes with Firebase.

Comment: but that dont create some inconsistency with nullable types and things become weird designed just bc of this requirement?

Comment: I'm not sure about it,  you'll have to test. That requirement is said in the Firebase Documentation.