# Reading data from firebase using Kotlin

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have the following data base [image]

I want to read the accounts of each user and I'm using the following code

```
        database.getReference("users").child(user!!.uid).child("accounts")
        .addValueEventListener(object  : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError?) {
          }

        override fun onDataChange(snaphsot: DataSnapshot?) {

            for (snap in snaphsot!!.children) {

           val account = snap.getValue(Account::class.java)

            }
        }

    })
```

But I'm getting this error

```
Account is missing a constructor with no arguments
```

How can I fix this?

**Edit:** Here is the Account class

```
data class Account(val name : String, val iowe : Double, val theyowe : Double, val notes : String)
```

Comment: make sure to create default constructor in your Account class
it will be better if you share your Account class source code here

Comment: Can you please show the Account class? Or read the Kotlin docs about how to define a constructor?

Comment: As cricket_0007 says, have a look at how to define a non-argument constructor. But it's likely the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563197/class-is-missing-a-constructor-with-no-arguments-but-ive-provided-a-construct and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287811/empty-constructor-for-kotlin-object-to-use-firebase

Comment: @hakim I added the Account class as an edit to the question

Comment: @cricket_007 I added the Account class to the original question