# Retrieve data from Firebase where is "params" are variable

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have a data class where I retrieve Firebase information. It looks similar to this:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class EventData(var eventEmoji: String = "",
                            var PlanType: PlanType = PlanType.CUSTOM_TYPE_1,
                            var accel: Boolean = false,
                            var latitude: String = "0.0",
                            var longitude: String = "0.0",
                            var initialDate: String = "",
                            var finalDate: String = "",
                            var initialHour: String = "",
                            var finalHour: String = "",
                            var plae: String = "",
                            var addr: String = "",
                            var description: String = "",
                            var adminProfileImageUrl: String = "") : Serializable
```

The problem that I'm facing now, is that exist a new data information that before was unused.

But this new field can exist or not depending on Business people. That field contains some translations, but... not always are the same or same number of it.

Example how is in Firebase:

[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve all this data in the `EventData` class.

I tried to add the new attribute as:

`var localizable: Map<Any,Any>? = hashMapOf()`

`var localizable: Map<String,Any>? = hashMapOf()`

`var localizable: Map<String,String>? = hashMapOf()`

`var localizable: Map<String,SpecificClass>? = hashMapOf()`

But... doesn't work.

Is possible to achieve?

Comment: try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563197/class-is-missing-a-constructor-with-no-arguments-but-ive-provided-a-construct and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287811/empty-constructor-for-kotlin-object-to-use-firebase

Comment: Have you tried to declare it like this `var localizable: Map<String,Any>? = hashMapOf()` and get it accordingly? What is happening in this case? Please responde with @.